# What is the best way to find the only unique value in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What is the best way (efficient) to find the ONLY unique value in an array **in terms of Time Complexity**.

**Example:**

- `findUniq([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])` should return `2`
- `findUniq([3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])` should return `4`

**Constrains:**

The array has more than **2** values to begin with.

The array only has numbers.

The array only has one unique value, such as [1, 7, 1, 1] or [4, 2, 2, 2]

[3, 4, 5, 3] is not a valid input.

I am wondering if I can use `Set` to solve this problem.

This is the solution with a for loop, I am not sure if this solution will pass all scenarios.

```
 let findUniq = (arr) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[0]) {
      return arr[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is [3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5] a valid input?

Comment: No, the array will only has one unique value.

Comment: The code in the question does not produce a correct result in the first place, for example it will fail on [1,2,3,1,2].

Comment: How do you define "best"? Shortest code? Asymptotic complexity? Average runtime complexity?

Comment: Please clarify: Can the array only contain two different values or more than two values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `find` method and check if `indexOf` is equal to `lastIndexOf`. It will return first match and stop the loop.

```js
const uniq = arr => arr.find((e, i) => arr.indexOf(e) == arr.lastIndexOf(e));

console.log(uniq([3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]));
console.log(uniq([1, 2, 3, 1, 2]));
console.log(uniq([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: this finds the first occurrence of a unique value, but doesn't answer if it's the only unique value.

Comment: `const uniq = arr.filter((e) => arr.indexOf(e) == arr.lastIndexOf(e)).length === 1`

Comment: @cgTag The OP says that "The array only has one unique value."

Comment: @ChrisHappy oh okay. Seems less difficult then and thus less fun to solve.

Comment: @cgTag We're off to see the challenge, the challenge of PPCG! xD

Comment: @cgTag You did mean `const uniq = (arr) => arr.filter((e) => arr.indexOf(e) == arr.lastIndexOf(e)).length === 1` ... right? ... and more or less difficult comes down to a simple spelling, like `find` vs `filter` for the answers given sample

Answer (score 2):

Solution based off where element #1 equals element #2 in the array.

The one liner: `const unique = arr => (arr[0] === arr[1]) ? arr.find((x) => x !== arr[0]) : (arr[0] === arr[2]) ? arr[1] : arr[0];`

**Slightly more readable:**

```js
const unique = arr =>
  (arr[0] === arr[1])
    ? arr.find((x) => x !== arr[0])
    : (arr[0] === arr[2]) ? arr[1] : arr[0];


console.log(
  unique([2, 1, 2, 2]),
  unique([2, 3, 3]),
  unique([4, 4, 4, 3]),
  unique([4]) //Thanks Slai
);
```

**Requirements**:

- Contains only 2 different numbers.
- Only 1 unique value

**More Readable**

```js
const unique = arr => {
  if (arr[0] === arr[1])
    return arr.find((x) => x !== arr[0] );
  else 
    return (arr[0] === arr[2]) ? arr[1] : arr[0];
}

var arr = [2, 1, 2, 2],
    arr1 = [2, 3, 3],
    arr2 = [4, 4, 4, 3],
    arr3 = [4]; //Thanks Slai

console.log(unique(arr), unique(arr1), unique(arr2), unique(arr3));
```

**More efficient?**

```js
function unique(arr) {
  if (arr[0] === arr[1]) {
    for (let i = 2, x = arr.length; i < x; i++) // Using 2 because  0 & 1 are dups
      if (arr[i] !== arr[0]) return arr[i];
  } else {
    return (arr[0] === arr[2]) ? arr[1] : arr[0];
  }  
}

var arr = [2, 1, 2, 2],
    arr1 = [2, 3, 3],
    arr2 = [4, 4, 4, 3],
    arr3 = [4]; //Thanks Sali

console.log(unique(arr), unique(arr1), unique(arr2), unique(arr3));
```

Comment: length is 1 or greater than 2 (seems to work with 1 too)

Comment: @Slai Thanks! I thought there would be an error trying to reference `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`, but nothing. Thanks again!

Comment: @Slai Thanks! I'm going to pretend that I have autocorrect.... >.> xD

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
var unique = function(xs) {
  return xs.filter(function(x, i) {
    return xs.indexOf(x) === i
  })
}
```

this code retuns all elements without repeating 
use two loop to compare each elements of array with other if there is another one break the loop else finally retunr it

```
function unique(arr) {
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    for (var j=i; j<arr.length; j++)
    if(arr[i] != arr[j]) continue
    if (j== arr.length) return i
    break
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this removes all the duplicates, not return only unique as OP stated.

Comment: edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a count map and than iterate over your map and find the element with count 1.

Time Complexity : O(n)

```js
var arr = [3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
var map = arr.reduce((a,val)=>{
  a[val] = (a[val]? a[val]+1 :1) ;
  return a;
},{});
var result;
Object.keys(map).forEach((key)=>{
  if(map[key] === 1)
    result = key;
});
console.log(result);
```

If every repeated element in array is repeated even number of times than you can simply use `Xor` operator:

```js
var findUnique = (arr)=> arr.reduce((a,val)=> a^val,0);

console.log(findUnique([3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,5,5,3,3]));
console.log(findUnique([2,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]));
```

Comment: My head just exploded.

Comment: fails for [3, 4, 4, 4]

Comment: @mehulmpt updated

Answer (score 0):

While i really like the `.reduce`, `.filter`, `.find` and `Set` approaches to this problem, i think it can be solved more easily - i am not so sure how this would translate into actual costs given the different scenarios, all i can say is that if the loop encounters a known value it skips further processing, and for each new value it checks if there is another same value behind its found position.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'uniqueValue', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  get: function() {
    let found = [];
    for(let n of this) {
      if(n in found) continue;
      if(this.indexOf(n, this.indexOf(n)+1) === -1) return n;
      found.push(n);
    }
  }
});

console.log([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].uniqueValue)
console.log([3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3].uniqueValue)
console.log([3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9].uniqueValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can think of some ways to accomplish this:

1. Using a `Set`

```js
const arr = [2,1,1,1,1];

const value = new Set(arr).values().next();

console.log(value.value);
```

2. Using `find`

```js
const arr = [3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3];

const value = arr.find(value => arr.filter(x => x === value).length === 1);

console.log(value);
```

3. Using `reduce`

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4];

const value = arr.reduce((current, val) => current === val ? 0 : current);

console.log(value);
```